# AWS Nitro enclave shutting down automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have created a nitro-based ec2 instance by using instance type c6a.8xlarge and have created a NodeJS-based application.

Enclave was generated by using the following command and the .eif file was successfully created

**Command = nitro-cli build-enclave --docker-uri ec2-user/nitro-test-app:latest --output-file nitro-enclave.eif**

Enclave was run by using the following command.

**Command = nitro-cli run-enclave --cpu-count 2 --memory 3524 --eif-path nitro-test.eif --debug-mode**

The results of the run command were as follows

Start allocating memory...
Started enclave with enclave-cid: 16, memory: 3524 MiB, cpu-ids: [1, 17]

{
"EnclaveName": "hello",
"EnclaveID": "i-096e001cdd5c912c9-enc182d5585cfe18db",
"ProcessID": 7666,
"EnclaveCID": 16,
"NumberOfCPUs": 2,
"CPUIDs": [
1,
17
],
"MemoryMiB": 3524
}

But when we run the command to check the results of the started enclave the results were empty

**Command = nitro-cli describe-enclaves
Result = []**

Below are the results of the logs

**Logs:**

[enc-*******0f0dc91:***0][WARN][2022-08-24T22:35:28.916Z][src/enclave_proc/mod.rs:207] Received hang-up event from the enclave. The enclave process will shut down.

[enc-*******0f0dc91:***0][INFO][2022-08-24T22:35:28.916Z][src/enclave_proc/mod.rs:541] Enclave process 5430 exited event loop.

What could be the possible reason that the enclave instance is immediately stopping after instantiating?

Comment: c6a.8xlarge is amd64 CPU. nitro instances have a "g" instead of "a" eg c7g.8xlarge and are ARM cpus

Comment: @jordanm FYI c7g.8xlarge is not nitro supported.